# Передача картинки на сервер и её получение, проблема в одинаковом нейминге картинки!

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Я передаю картинку на сервер задаю ей имя пользователя, потом получаю её с сервера в профиль.
Проблема заключается в том что когда я хочу поменять картинку у пользователя я её меняю и отправляю с тем же именем с которым на сервере лежит другая его картинка, на сервере она меняется, но на фронте отображается не новая а старая.(Может где то в куки сохраняется или ещё что то).

```
                    <img
                  className="teacher_photo_img"
                  src={
                    this.state.url !== null
                      ? this.state.url
                      : this.props.teacherProf[0] !== undefined
                      ? "http://192.168.11.252:8008/images/" +
                        this.props.teacherProf[0].imageName
                      : "http://192.168.11.252:8008/images/none.jpg"
                  }
                  onError={({ currentTarget }) => {
                    currentTarget.src =
                      "http://192.168.11.252:8008/images/none.jpg";
                  }}
                />
```

Получаю её таким образом отправляю на сервер в виде файла через formData.
Когда перехожу по ссылке через браузер картинка отображается уже измененная, но на сайте сколько бы не обновлял страницу почему то грузит старую которой уже нет на сервере с чем это может быть связано!(Браузер Opera GX)

Comment: Скорее всего, старая картинка остаётся в кэше сайта / промежуточном кэще, который следует очистить от старой информации/сообщить об обновлении.

Comment: игнорирование кэша решило проблему, спасибо